How LEptons in Muonium are INteracting with Gravity? (LEMING-Experiment, Soter et al.)
How LEptons in Muonium are INteracting with Gravity? (LEMING experiment, Soter et al.)
I have read an article from the Physical Society Zurich, Switzerland about Prof. Dr. Anna Sótér planned LEMING experiment – measuring how LEptons in Muonium are INteracting with Gravity.

"In this newly approved LEMING experiment at the Paul Scherrer Institute we aspire to carry out next generation atomic physics and gravity experiments using muonium, which is an exotic atom consisting purely leptons, a muon and an electron (Mu = μ⁺ + e⁻)."


"No one has ever seen muonium atoms fall, which consist only of leptons and are therefore not determined by the strong nuclear force,” explains Prof. Dr. Anna Sótér (ETH Zürich). This is set to change soon..."

Source: www.pgz.ch/events/ws2324/event.20231109/index.html
Is there already anything published? Anyway, comments on the general idea underlying the LEMING experiment are appreciated.

Free fall of muonium, principle of measurement (proposal for the LEMING experiment, Soter et al.)

The linked page looks like part of a conference agenda. Are you asking for links to other literature?

The LEMING experiment was suggested by Prof. Dr. Anna Sótér (ETH Zürich) back in 2022, so I was wondering, whether first results are available and already published. Meanwhile I have also contacted Prof. Dr. Anna Sótér  directly via Email. However, please don't hesitate to comment if you have any update or more detailed information on the innovative LEMING experiment. Thanks!

Oh, that looks to me like a five-to-ten year experiment.

Your assessment on the anticipated availability of results for the innovative LEMING experiment (Soter et al.) is helpful. If muonium atoms were not subject to gravity, this would be quite an achievement, although in my view, muonium atoms will behave predictably and fall completely normally. Actually, I did not ask for resource recommendation. Thanks!

@UN73 You've written "Is there already anything published?", which I believe is why your question was tagged as a resource recommendation one. (that, and there isn't any other question in your post).

I also kindly requested to discuss the general idea underlying the LEMING experiment. For example, I can imgagine that a direct gravity experiment using muonium is inherently challenging due to the short lifetime (τ ∼ 2.2 µs) of the µ+ and the fact that muonium atoms must be created in matter, while experiments must be carried out in vacuo. However, researchers at the Paul Scherrer Institute (PSI, Switzerland) meanwhile succeeded in developing a novel cold atomic beam of muonium (Mu = μ⁺ + e⁻) in vacuum...

@UN73 In that case, note that this isn't the right platform for an open ended discussion, and such questions are usually closed due to lacking focus. In other words, questions here are required to really be questions... (BTW, you may try the chat for that purpose)

An answer to the real and very concrete key question in the title and in the first sentence of my post is still missing. How Leptons are interacting with gravity or in other words what is actually going on with the gravitational field of Leptons such as an electron (quantum object) e.g. in the double-slit experiment? It is a simple question and we just don't know it, or do we (Yes/No)?

@UN73 I think everyone read that question as part of the title of the experiment you mention, not as an actual question. So if you want to focus on the actual question rather on the experiment I think you should edit your question to clarify that point.

It might also be appropriate to ask a companion question that is specifically about the physics. In that case you would want to link both questions to each other, and explain clearly the difference between this question (which really seems like a request for publications about one specific experiment) versus a question about purely leptonic gravity as a natural phenomenon.
